# Sort Gregorian date in Power BI

Tags: slider, powerbi, dashboard, powerbi-desktop

In power bi, I have a date table containing gregorian date and solar date since 1970. how I can sort the solar month? or how can I sort slider containing alphabetic other than  English?

Comment: Please add some data with your desired output.

Comment: my date table contains fields: GDate, GYear, GMonth, GDay, SDate, SYear, SMonth, SDay, this table contains all days since 1970 for example  9/2/2020, 2020,  02, 09, 12/06/1399 1399 06 12. Now I wanna use the field SMonth in a slider sorted from 1 to 12 . How I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you wants your Month name to order in the slicer **alphabetically** (like first A then B.... finally Z), rather than using Month value, you can create a **Custom column** in your Date table with **Month** name for each date.

Once you created the new **Custom column** in the source, change the type to Text/General. Now create your Month slicer using this new **Custom column**. This will now show the month names using alphabetic order.

You can use both DAX and Power Query to get the month name from a Date value.

```
DAX: MonthName = FORMAT([Date],"mmmm")
M/Power Query: MonthName = Date.MonthName(date_column_name, "en-US")
```

Finally convert the data type as Text/General.

**Process of creating new custom column**

Right click on the Date table and select New Custom Column as shown in the below image-

[image]

Now put the DAX code and change the data type as shown in the below image-

[image]

Comment: thank you but I don't know how to add values to the measure column.

Comment: I have done live connect to ssas and I cannot find add a new column

Comment: also, I want to be ordered based on the Persian language.

Comment: Try to create columns in SSAS, and you also need another numeric column to control the ordering if Persian do not give your normal alphabetic ordering.